# About tags [cart], [shopping] and [shopping-cart]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, there are about 1k questions with [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart), 200 with [shopping](/questions/tagged/shopping) and 500 with [cart](/questions/tagged/cart).

It seems that [shopping](/questions/tagged/shopping) is mostly used as synonym of [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) (I didn't suggest a synonym because I don't participate in either.) In such cases, [shopping](/questions/tagged/shopping) usually comes along with [cart](/questions/tagged/cart). In fact the intersection of these last 2 tags is about 100 questions.

The problem is [cart](/questions/tagged/cart)... There seems to be two clear distinct uses of this tag. The first one is explained above. The second use is as an acronym of [Classification And Regression Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics#Classification_and_regression_trees), which is a relatively common usage in statistical jargon. Thus, questions tagged [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [cart](/questions/tagged/cart) almost certainly mean the second case.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: `How can this be fixed?` I'd say, with a flamethrower. On the tags and possibly many of the questions, too.

Comment: I would lean toward burninating 'shopping' and making 'cart' a synonym of 'classification-and-regression-trees' (or a slightly shorter version, if it exists). I am not sure how tag synonyms work, however: if someone tags a question 'cart', will 'classification-and-regression-trees' be displayed, thus revealing any usage errors?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because you didn't link it: http://media.screened.com/uploads/0/4246/442004-scorpio_flamethrower_super.png

Comment: I retagged the [r] questions to [cart-analysis].  Hopefully that's still plenty discoverable to avoid recurrence of this problem.