# Should [basket] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

As a result of reading [this question about carts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188305/188613) I noticed another seemingly useless tag - [basket](/questions/tagged/basket).

The tag-wiki is empty, and it seems that most if not all of the questions using that tag are referring to online shopping baskets. There's only 31 questions using that tag so manually re-tagging it out of existence wouldn't be hard. I'd do it myself, but I wanted to make sure there's not some legitimate use of the tag that I'm unaware of.

Comment: having a tag for shopping carts doesn't sound like a terrible tag; it should probably have a better name though, like `shopping-cart`.

Comment: If the tag-wiki is empty, just put something in the basket so users can check it out .... yeah, I'll leave.

Comment: **-1** your edit summary capitalised `jQuery` wrong.

Comment: @michael Bugger. How do I edit an incorrect edit summary in MSO?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I don't think there's an obvious way; you *might* (nobody's really sure) have been able to do it by editing again inside the grace period, but the grace period's up now.

Comment: Of all the things to burninate, we have to burninate baskets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just edited the ~30 questions that used [basket](/questions/tagged/basket) to remove that tag (and fix other glaring errors).

In many cases it was replaced with [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) (which should probably be related to [cart](/questions/tagged/cart) in some fashion), and [market-basket-analysis](/questions/tagged/market-basket-analysis) was also created to differentiate that use.  There might be enough usage to justify [magento-basket](/questions/tagged/magento-basket), but for now it doesn't exist.

Comment: So problem solved, I guess? As far as [shopping-cart] -> [cart], the linked question indicates there might be some problems with that. Accepted, even if you stole 31 edits from me on my badge hunting.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yeah, for that few questions it seemed easier to just fix things rather than discussing.  Any halfway informed discussion would mean looking at a bunch of those questions and if I'm already there...

Comment: Better to ask for forgiveness than permission? I'll keep that in mind...

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a synonym for [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart). *cart* is commonly used in the US, whereas *basket* in the UK.

As a reference: ["Shopping basket" or "shopping cart"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29356/shopping-basket-or-shopping-cart).

That being said I'd treat [basket](/questions/tagged/basket) as identical to [shopping-cart](/questions/tagged/shopping-cart)

Comment: For us in the UK a cart is something pulled by a horse

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought as well. It does seem that people are taking my tongue in cheek title a little too literally, though.

Comment: See also: [[cart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cart)]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a lost in translation thing?

Not everyone in the world calls it a cart maybe?

Or maybe some posters use online translation tools to ask questions and getting a basket instead of a cart.